# Adding Google Map Fragment to an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-fragmentactivity

In my app, I only want to show the `Google Map` when a user taps a button. So, I created a subclass of `SupportMapFragment` and am now wanting to add that `Fragment` to my `FragmentActivity` using:

```
Fragment map = new ZSSGoogleMap();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.rootFrame, map);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But, I keep getting an error on the first line telling me I need to cast it to `ZSSGoogleMap`.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I have worked with `Fragments` before and done exactly what I am trying to do here.

Comment: What error you are getting ? Please post your error also.

Comment: It is just telling me to cast the first line. Added screenshot.

Comment: Try to write it this way: `ZSSGoogleMap map = new ZSSGoogleMap();`

Comment: I realize that I can do that, but the `add()` function doesn't take anything but a `Fragment` as an argument. So I get an error.

Comment: As you are using  `SupportMapFragment` so ,You will have to also use `getSupportFragmentManager();` .

Comment: Ah, looks like I was using the wrong imports. Needed to import from the v4 support package.

Comment: Yes if you are using Fragments below API 3.0 then you will have to add all the packages which contain `v4.support` only.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: Yes i have posted it as answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Fragments` below API level 3.0 then you will have to use the Packages of `v4.support` for the `Fragments` and your Fragment will `SupportFragment` only.

As you are using `SupportMapFragment` so ,You will have to also use `getSupportFragmentManager();`

Answer (score 0):

try this way if you want to use google map

```
MapFragment fragmentManager = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);;
```

or if want to use support library then

```
 SupportMapFragment fragmentManager = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    GoogleMap map= fragmentManager.getMap()
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.rootFrame, map);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: How would this help me? The `GoogleMap` is not part of my main activity, it is part of the `Fragment` that I want to add.

Comment: this is also part of fragment why guys down vote any one suggest me?

Comment: Its because the problem is not about using GoogleMap fragment Its about for using supportmapfragment.

Comment: So I already given the optoin if you using support library then you can use this way